# How to replace multiple newlines in a row with one newline using Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, newline

I have a script written in ruby. I need to remove any duplicate newlines (e.g.)

```
\n
\n
\n
```

to

```
\n
```

My current attempt worked (or rather not) using

```
str.gsub!(/\n\n/, "\n")
```

Which gave me no change to the output. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

$s = "foo\n\n\nbar\nbaz\n\n\nquux";

puts $s

$s.gsub!(/[\n]+/, "\n");

puts $s
```

Comment: Since that was a year ago, I have no idea.  I expect that I tried /\n+/, as that is what I would use in Perl, and it didn't work for me, probably because I did something else wrong.

Comment: I think s.gsub!(/\n+/, "\n") works. At least it works in my laptop.

Comment: Per @Keng's answer below, if you're down this path and it doesn't seem to be working, be sure to check `/[\r\n]+/` -- this can occur outside of Windows too. (eg, my scenario is textarea input on a Rails site hosted on my Linux box)

Answer (score 20):

Use the more idiomatic `String#squeeze` instead of `gsub`.

```
str = "a\n\n\nb\n\n\n\n\n\nc"
str.squeeze("\n") # => "a\nb\nc"
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to match more than one newline up to an infinite amount. Your code example will work with just a minor tweak:

```
str.gsub!(/\n+/, "\n")
```

For example:

```
str = "this\n\n\nis\n\n\n\n\na\ntest"
str.gsub!(/\n+/, "\n")  # => "this\nis\na\ntest"
```

Answer (score 7):

are you sure it shouldn't be /\n\n\n/, "\n"  that what you seem to be wanting in your question above.

also, are you sure it's not doing a windows new-line "\r\n"?

**EDIT: Additional info**

Per Comment

> "The amount of newlines can change. Different lines have between 2 and 5 newlines."

if you only want to hit the 2-5 lines try this

```
/\n{2,5}/, "\n"
```

Comment: The amount of newlines can change. Different lines have between 2 and 5 newlines.

Comment: Many thanks for the `\r\n` callout. For what it's worth, it's not only Windows, either -- I ran into this when using data from a textarea input on a Rails site on my Linux box. Granted, other factors may be affecting the data as well, but the point is that Windows is not one of them.

Comment: \r\n worked perfectly. Spent 1.5hr to find the perfect solution and here it is. Thanks @Keng

Answer (score 6):

Simply splitting and recombining the lines will give the desired result

```
>> "one\ntwo\n\nthree\n".split.join("\n")
=> "one\ntwo\nthree"
```

Edit: I just noticed this will replace ALL whitespace substrings with newlines, e.g.

```
>> "one    two three\n".split.join("\n")
=> "one\ntwo\nthree"
```

First check that this is what you want!

Comment: nice one - that is great way to do it!

Comment: Thanks, I selected this as the answer but then realised it splits on spaces too, which isn't good in my case. Sorry about that.

Comment: You're right.  You could use str.split(/\n+/) but Chas. Owens' solution is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Simply calling split will also trim out all of your whitespace.

You need to pass `\n` to split

```
>> "one   ok \ntwo\n\nthree\n".split(/\n+/).join("\n")
=> "one  ok \ntwo\nthree"
```

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, also works with

- spaces on blank lines
- n number of back to back blank lines

> str.gsub! /\n^\s*\n/, "\n\n"

where,

- \n is of course newline
- \s is space
- denotes 1 or more spaces along when used after \s

Comment: Hardly any of these address the `\r` character. I'd modify this to the following: `str.gsub(/[\n\r]+^\s*[\r\n]+/, "\n\n")`

Answer (score -1):

Try This It Worked for me:

```
s = test\n\n\nbar\n\n\nfooo 

s.gsub("\n\n", '')
```

Answer (score -2):

Ruby needs the backslashes escaped differently than you have provided.

```
str.sub!("\\\\n+\\\\n","\\\\n")
```

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/176239